# How do I use sharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I have an Android app which in one of the activities the user check one of the radio buttons. I want to save the user's choice and use its value in another activity.

Comment: This is pretty basic and explained in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 1):

To store

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
prefs.edit().putBoolean("KEY", your_boolean).commit();
```

To retrieve

```
Boolean your_boolean = prefs.getBoolean("KEY", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preference for saving the values.

For Saving value into SharedPreferences use below code

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                        "SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("radio_value", value);
                editor.commit();
```

For Retriving value from SharedPreferences use below code

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String storedValue = prefs.getString("radio_value","");
```